# SSIS how to save all files in UTF-8 format in a particular folder?

Tags: utf-8, ssis

I have many files 100 + in a folder which particular package is giving as a output.
From this folder I am currently manually saving all files in UTF -8 format before giving them for load into SAP server. This I am doing manually , Opening file in notepad then click on Save as , select UTF-8 as encoding and then save it.
But to do this for more than 100 files is really very time wasting and also leads to some human error.

I am aware about Flat file destination encoding but that is not converting the files in UTF-8 format , If i select this encoding on flat file destination and write output , then when i open that file in notepad again and when i click on save as I should see UTF-8 as encoding , but it is showing me ANSI.

Any help will save much time..

Comment: Did you check (FlatFileDestination as UTF8) the file in Notepad++, there is a menu at the top called **Encoding** where you can see the default selected Encoding.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using an 'execute process task'.

**1. Create a powershell script that changes the encoding on each file:**
[image]

**2. Save this script in a directory that is accessible by the ssis service account.**

**3. Add an 'execute process task' to your control flow.**

**4. Set the appropriate configuration values.** 
[image]